# chartValueSelected from daniel gindi's Charts is not working with CandleStickChart

Tags: ios, swift, candlestick-chart

I have been trying to throw all candle stick values (high, low, open, and close) into four separate labels. To get the selected candle values, I would like to use:

```
func chartValueSelected(_ chartView: ChartViewBase, entry: ChartDataEntry, highlight: Highlight) {...}
```

This however, only provides x and y values. I tried changing the function to:

```
func chartValueSelected(_ chartView: ChartViewBase, entry: CandleChartDataEntry, highlight: Highlight) {...}
```

But thats now working as well... Any help will be greatly appreciated. :)